# Shopify Theme Gem Install Location (Mac Terminal)

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems, shopify

I'm new to using Terminal, and I'm wondering where the files for my theme are being installed using Shopify Theme Gem. I've gone through the installation instructions on GitHub (https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_theme) and I've looked through the documentation provided by Shopify, but I haven't seen where I'm downloading the theme files I'll be editing (or where I should put them myself if I'm customizing Timber).

When I generated the API key and password and ran `theme configure [MyAPIKey] [MyPassword] [MyStoreURL]`, it put the config.yml file in my User folder, which I don't think is the correct place.

When I ran `theme download` it installed some files in my Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory, but no .liquid theme files.

The documentation I've seen so far isn't very specific, at least for me. Where/how should I be installing everything? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use that gem all the time. You should make a directory for your work under your User account called "work" or whatever you like. Using the terminal cd into that new directory and commence the following pattern:

mkdir foomanchu                   <=== makes a directory for a store with name foomanchu
cd foomanchu
theme configure api pwd theme_id #
theme download

I use version control by git, so I also do:

git init
git add .
git commit -am 'initial commit of foomanchu'

and now I work... and it is pretty much as good as it gets.

You should use Timber from Shopify if you're a rookie though... I have 30 years experience with the command line and you probably don't.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed your directions and now have my "config.yml" file in a specified directory. However, I'm still unsure how to get the theme files.

When I run "theme download", it looks like it's putting files in "Library/Ruby/Gems/..." and "System/Library/Frameworks/...", but still no .liquid theme files for Timber (which I have as a disabled theme in my store and which I used for the "theme_id"). Do I just add those to my "foomanchu" directory myself?

Sorry if I'm being obtuse. Definitely new to command line. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you know how I should import or load those theme files? I'm still not sure from the documentation I've found online. Thanks.

Comment: @StephSharp Can you tell me where I should be seeing or downloading the theme files to?

Comment: @Magadog If you run `theme download` within the directory containing your config.yml file your theme files will be downloaded into that directory. Make sure you're in the correct directory to begin with, and then check what happens when you run `theme download`. Any errors?

Comment: @StephSharp It looks like I'm getting a socket error
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in 'initialize': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)` And thanks for getting back to me, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @StephSharp Got it! I had "http://" preceding my shop URL in the config file. Removing that and running "theme download" finally worked. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Magadog Great! No problems :)

Comment: Shameless promotion: I created a command line sync for our in-house designer to use. You may like it better than the shopify_theme gem. https://github.com/internalfx/quickshot

Comment: @Magadog THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!! THIS WAS MY EXACT PROBLEM FROM ALSO NOT CD'ING TO MY PROPER THEME DIR! YESSSSSSSSSSS!!!!!!!!!!!!